# How to Use Interface in my Code to make it more scalabale?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop, design-patterns

I have a ASP.NET web application which has a UI project and BL project. The BL project handles all business logic and data access part.I call the BL methods from my UI by Simply calling the method on the instances.

```
Public Class User

    Public Property UserID As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    //rest of the properties for user


  Public Sub Save()
   //save the details to the database
  End sub
End Class
```

and from my UI (its in C#) i do this.

```
  User objUser=new User();
  objUser.FirstName="Happy";
  objUser.Save();
```

Everything works fine. Since the project is growing, i thought about trying to add some kind of unit testing/dependency injections tests. Googled around and saw every example uses Interfaces. I read so much about interfaces but don't know how to include interfaces in my coding and makes it to follow  a better (scalable & testable) pattern. Other than testability, will it give me some other advantage ?

Can someone provide me a sample how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) design pattern and the [asp.net mvc framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc). There is a good overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28VS.98%29.aspx) that explains the benefits of this design strategy.

An excerpt here:

> The MVC pattern helps you create applications that separate the
>   different aspects of the application (input logic, business logic, and
>   UI logic), while providing a loose coupling between these elements.
>   The pattern specifies where each kind of logic should be located in
>   the application. The UI logic belongs in the view. Input logic belongs
>   in the controller. Business logic belongs in the model. This
>   separation helps you manage complexity when you build an application,
>   because it enables you to focus on one aspect of the implementation at
>   a time. For example, you can focus on the view without depending on
>   the business logic.
>
> The loose coupling between the three main components of an MVC
>   application also promotes parallel development. For example, one
>   developer can work on the view, a second developer can work on the
>   controller logic, and a third developer can focus on the business
>   logic in the model.

Comment: Can you answer with my specific user example. some sample code ?

Comment: @Happy: I'm prepping for and then off to a meeting shortly. Perhaps after that if you still haven't had any help I can post something. In the meantime, check out the links. They explain the advantages. There are also tutorials here (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) that could get you started to see how everything works. With MVC, it's not as simple as just throwing an interface or two here and there. It's an entire design methodology.

Answer (score 1):

**Coding to interfaces** gives plenty of advantages, better testability being one side-effect related to the main advantage: **decoupling an object from its dependencies**.

Say I have a class A, and in its implementation it uses class B. If you don't provide an interface to B, then you **tightly coupled the design of A and B together** (you cannot consider A without this specific implementation of B, as it uses the concrete implementation).

If you write an interface to B (say IB) and use it in A instead of using directly B, then you **decoupled the design**, and made them independent. A is now able to function independently of the specific inplementation B, it only knows an interface to it (IB) and the methods it needs to run on it. So if later on, you decide that your implementation of B wasn't good, or if you want to have A able to work on two different IB depending on the context, you can replace B with B2, **which also implements IB**, so you don't have to modify A at all.

The action to create A by injecting an implementation of IB at runtime like that:

```
A myA = new A(new B());  // this could also be new A(new B2()); or anythign else that implements IB
```

is called **dependency injection**, and is the best way to achieve a much desirable feature of OO programming: **inversion of control** (It's not A that control the behaviour of its dependencies anymore, it's an independent class - the factory - that controls what is injected into A).

---

For **testability purpose**, you can then **unit-test A without making assumptions on B** (which obviously needs to be tested separately). So in your tests, you can inject into A a stub or a mocked implementation of B, that will help you test the behaviour you want.

*(Sorry no actual codes examples, as I'm a Java developer and not very good with the syntax of C#)*

Comment: How do i do with my User Class here  ? should i have an IUser Interface ? and i call iUser.save method ?

Comment: Having an interface to your User is only helpful if you plan to use that User from another class (test does not count). You then use IUser in that other class, and when you want to test that other class, you don't need to provide a "real" user, but can stub/mock it instead.

Comment: But for a class as simple as your User, I'm not sure an interface would be really adapted, although I would probably create an interface for the Save method - or better, move that save method away from the User and in a data-access-layer: dao.SaveUser(user)

Comment: @Guillaume: I would say that testing most definitely DOES count.  Anytime that a class exposes something as non-private, it should be considered viable to make it part of an interface.  Not necessarily required, but not bad form to do so.

Comment: Depends which class... do you put getters and setters for beans on interface? I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a description of functionality for a class.  Any class that implements the interface must implement the interface's properties, methods, indexers, and/or events.  An interface contains no implementation, only the signatures for the functionality the interface provides.

There are a few advantages to using interfaces.  One of the big ones is that it allows you to get around the lack of multiple inheritance in .NET.  You cannot inherit from multiple classes in .NET, but you can implement multiple interfaces.

Other benefits include loose coupling, easier maintainability, and makes code reuse more accessible since implementation is separated from the interface.

Here's a simple example of how your code could use an interface (using VB.NET):

```
Public Interface iPerson
    Property FirstName As String
    Property LastName As String
    'Rest of properties for a person

    Sub Save()
End Interface

Public Class User
    Implements iPerson

    Public Property UserId As Integer

    Public Property FirstName As String Implements iPerson.FirstName
    Public Property LastName As String Implements iPerson.LastName

    Public Sub Save() Implements iPerson.Save
        'Add code to save user
    End Sub
End Class
```

And from your UI you could then do:

```
Dim objUser as iPerson = New User

objUser.FirstName = "Bob"
objUser.LastName = "Mckenzie"
ctype(objUser, User).UserId = 12345
```

If you then decided to create a new class implementing iPerson (ie - SuperUser) most of the code in your UI could remain the same:

```
Dim objUser as iPerson = New SuperUser

objUser.FirstName = "Bob"
objUser.LastName = "Mckenzie"

'The next line would throw a runtime error since object is not of type user
ctype(objUser, User).UserId = 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a layer to bridge the UI and BL.  I'm not a fan of the UI knowing anything about the BL.  This can be accomplished with interfaces, but it doesn't need to be done with them.